# Redirect to HTTPS in under Zend Controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to redirect my application from http to https if I'm using a certain controller. How would I do this? I don't really want a .htaccess rewrite because I'm using lots of Zend routes preferably I'd like a method within Zend which can do it

Comment: Nice question. I had this situation when I had to forward the customer to payment gateway from notmal http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that for all actions inside your controller, you could perform the redirect in the `init()` function using the controller's `_redirect()` function:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
}
```